# Adjust column to fill width using css grid when one column is translated out of view

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with two columns:

`.main-content{ display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px auto; }`

The first column is a sidebar that is toggled. I want the second column to fill the entire screen after the first column is translated out of display.

The problem is that even after the first column is translated,

`.sidebar-close{ transform: translateX(-100%); transition: all 0.4s; }`

The second column still remains fixed at 200px from the left.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the right hand column not to be auto when the left hand column is out of view but you want it to be its natural width + 200px rather than just its natural (auto) width?

Comment: I want the second column to occupy the full width. Right now even when the left column is out of view, the right column is still 200px from the left.

Comment: Just to check - what is the full width? How is it determined. Is it really 200px plus whatever width the second column was originally? If so do you want the second column to change its layout as it moves across and becomes wider? (If it were to start at 1fr rather than auto I think things would be easier!)